# SSH root access configuration

Tags: root, openssh, sshd

What is a good configuration to allow ssh root access in order to set up your server?  Most of the time I have the connection closed but maintenance and setup requires as such.

I've been using the same configuration for the past 15 years; FreeBSD mostly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't allow SSH root access on your server. Allow only a small subset of nonprivileged users; have them added to the sudoers file so they can sudo root.

Here's an example of what you should have on your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin  no
AllowUsers       ahr 13nilux dr01
```

If you disable password-based authentication and allow only pubkey authentication to your server, it's even better.

Comment: And I think is one of the best to single out a user access. There are not that many anyway.
Now if feasible to issue a key for a particular user in addition to login. OpenSSL may be a good approach
But has been done already does complicate the setup? Any other simplistic way to single out?

Comment: The example is straightforward I appreciated very much! How do you disable public key as I ve been allowing RSAAuthentication yes
if i cut that down I am lost

Comment: A third element besides the classic login usually is hardening the security but here I have no idea where that may be. Public key anyone can get it but a private key I think is a success

Comment: ChallengeResponseAuthentication no # but how you get in? Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: Here's a link to information about sshd config: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd_config/ . About hardening the security, you can change the sshd server port to something different from 22 to prevent automated attacks. Installing fail2ban will be of help too.